# Why aren't there any single owner companies over a billion dollars?

Tags: equities, corporate-actions

The biggest companies have multiple owners which dilute the authority and finances of the company. They are either publicly traded companies via selling shares through stock markets, or privatly owned with multiple percentage of shares held by stake holders or board members. Why aren't there any billion dollar single owned companies (e.g. one founder who never sold his shares or gave up equity)?

Just curious because often times the founder(s) of a successful company, especially in tech startups have to bring their own idea to fruition from the early startup phase, often times carrying the company on their back for the first 6 months or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a question related to quantitative finance. I'm voting to close but I will answer your question.

I assume by "giving up equity", you exclude "giving up equity" to family or charitable trusts endowed by family. In that case, your premise is incorrect.

Bosch is one of the largest companies in the world by employee count. 100% of it is owned by the Bosch family and their foundation and I don't think they've ever had to sell their shares or give up equity. There are several other large companies in Europe and Asia that have been family-owned for their entire history. [Weyerhaeuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyerhaeuser) is family-owned and never had to give up equity as well.

It's rarer in the United States than in other countries. As naive as this sounds, it probably has to do with capitalism and corporate culture in the United States. The ecosystem for public funding in United States still completely dominates that in every other part of the world. From the day you start a company, you are led to believe (and I think it's both a justified and true belief) that it's better to own a small part of a large pie than a large part of a small pie. I think it's a good thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, i was seeking this for my own personal research purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're looking hard enough.

Several in here:
http://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/